# Linux Latest suexec error log messages cmd: suspendedpage.cgi

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

The function displays the most recent entries in your website’s error logs:

[2020-05-18 15:08:58]: uid: (1034/server) gid: (1037/server) cmd: suspendedpage.cgi

anybody knows what is this?

Comment: I assume this is your website on a shared / hosted provider. The same thing happened to me recently on a shared hosted account, even though my sites were fine.                                                                                                                                         2021-06-20 16:08:30]: uid: (1316/xxx) gid: (1318/xxx) cmd: suspendedpage.cgi.  I will keep an eye on it, but I think it is a one-off (provider updating scripts or similar). HTH.